# Display wordpress content on .NET website

Tags: c#, .net, wordpress

I'm developping a .NET website on which i'll display news, catégories, tags... of a wordpress website.
My goal is to benefit from the wordpress backoffice (ready to use).
I have ideas on how to do it but i wonder if i could find a .NET library to easily query the wordpress website.
Thank you.

Comment: This is a bit too broad to be answered, you should give us more details

Answer (score 0):

I would use the RSS feeds that wordpress has to offer. You can add '/feed' to any of the category or tag links to get specific info. I've used the following article to create a library to consume the feed:

http://blog.decayingcode.com/post/how-to-parse-an-rss-and-atom-feed-from-pure-net-without-plugins

Comment: Thank you. I think we'll try to use the xml rpc capabilities of Wordpress. We need to get categories, comments but also get and push comments to Wordpress. https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts

Comment: You could also use the REST API.

Comment: Thanks, it would be the best solution. Nevertheless, WP REST API looks rather recent. Did you implemented it? Is it stable enough?

Comment: Yes, it's very stable. It went through a long process before it was implemented in a Wordpress build. If my answer with the RSS feed is correct can please accept it?